# error while installing mediapipe_model_maker

Tags: python, installation, cmd, pip, mediapipe

I am trying to install `mediapipe_model_maker`, but this error is showing up:

```
ERROR: Cannot install mediapipe-model-maker==0.1.0.2, mediapipe-model-maker==0.1.1.0 and mediapipe-model-maker==0.1.1.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    mediapipe-model-maker 0.1.1.1 depends on mediapipe==0.9.2.1
    mediapipe-model-maker 0.1.1.0 depends on mediapipe==0.9.2.1
    mediapipe-model-maker 0.1.0.2 depends on mediapipe==0.9.0.1

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

How do I solve it? I didn't try anything, since I dont know what to do.

Comment: As you have used both the `python` and `pip` tags, the very least you should do is to [Edit] your question to include the command which is producing the error message, and which versions of those are involved.

Answer (score 0):

The package `mediapipe_model_maker` requires `mediatype`, which doesn't support all Python versions. Notably, there's [no Python 3.12 support](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/0.10.9/#files) at the moment, or 32-bit support.

Try installing Python 3.11 or lower, 64-bit.